# Emgu SURF feature matching issue

Tags: c#, surf, emgucv, orb

I am trying to detect an object using emgu SURF and ORB features with BruteForce matcher however, getting very wrong results as can be seen in the following pictures. The following two pictures are the results of surf and orb features matching respectively, with threshold 0.8 and k=2.
Can anyone please advise me how to fix this problem or it is just not possible to detect the object(drill) in this scene image? I am using the example SURF code in the emgu.I have tried many different values for threshold, k but never get acceptable results. Which part of the code could possibly contain errors; keypoint detection, feature extraction or matching? I have tried different keypoint detection and feature extraction methods like, sift, freak and brief but matching results are never better than the following. Please guide me.

Thanks

[image: SURF feature matching]

[image: ORB feature matching]